# C++ linking error with multiple .cpp files

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-2013

This is my header file. It complies just fine if I only include it in one .cpp file, but as soon as I try to include it in two or more .cpp files it creates an error as long as the maps are included in the header. I don't do anything but call the file in the .cpps.

```
#ifndef _TOOLS_H_
#define _TOOLS_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

map<char, string> d_one;
map<char, string> d_ten;

void smain();
string converter(int i);

string one(string in);
string two(string in);
string three(string in);
string four(string in);
string five(string in);
string six(string in);
string seven(string in);
string eight(string in);
string nine(string in);
string ten(string in);
#endif
```

This is the error Visual Studio 2013 gives me:

```
1>  Dictionary.cpp
1>  Funcion.cpp
1>  Main.cpp
1>Funcion.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::map<char,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<char>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<char const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > d_ten" (?d_ten@@3V?$map@DV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@D@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBDV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in Dictionary.obj
1>Funcion.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::map<char,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<char>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<char const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > d_one" (?d_one@@3V?$map@DV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@D@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBDV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in Dictionary.obj
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::map<char,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<char>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<char const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > d_ten" (?d_ten@@3V?$map@DV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@D@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBDV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in Dictionary.obj
1>Main.obj : error LNK2005: "class std::map<char,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<char>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<char const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > d_one" (?d_one@@3V?$map@DV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@D@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBDV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@A) already defined in Dictionary.obj
1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main
1>C:\Users\Vincent\Google Drive\Programming\C++\Challange\Release\Challange.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what `extern` is for.

In your header file:

```
extern map<char, string> d_one;
extern map<char, string> d_ten;
```

This says "these maps exist somewhere else" (instead of "create these maps").

In one (exactly one) source file:

```
map<char, string> d_one;
map<char, string> d_ten;
```